# Use jQuery timeago or momentjs and AngularJS together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to use [timeago plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/) to make dates look nicer. The problem is that these dates are fetched via AngularJS from the REST dynamically. So, when I attach this jQuery plugin to my page, it just doesn't process it.

So, how to better do such things? I would be happy to run without jQuery at all if possible.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I would use momentjs - http://momentjs.com/ - it has no dependencies.

Then you can just create a filter called 'timeAgo' or 'fromNow'.  You should probably call it `fromNow` because that's what momentjs calls it:

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('fromNow', function() {
  return function(date) {
    return moment(date).fromNow();
  }
});
```

Then you would just use simple data binding in your view:

```
<p>Pizza arrives {{pizzaArrivalDate | fromNow}}</p>
```

If you really wanted to use the jQuery plugin, you would probably have to write a directive. But that way of doing it is bad because it links your data to a DOM element.  The way I put above seperates data from DOM which is the angular way.  And it's pretty :-D

Comment: ...but this solution does not make the time get updated as time progresses, right?

Comment: It does not.  You would want a directive for that, one that would simply refresh the element every minute or so (you don't want it to cause a scope.$apply every minute, just update the element's text).

Comment: Took a while to figure out how to do it. Using the directive posted by "kwon" did not do it for me. Turns out, I had to watch the title attribute. See https://gist.github.com/JensRantil/5470122 for an example.

Comment: It should be noted that referencing `moment` from a global variable like that isn't really inline with best practices. injecting `$window` and getting it via `$window.moment` would be better... *Ideally*, however, you'd create a service for `moment` that you could inject into your filter. This would allow you to change your implementation at a later point via DI, and/or unit test more effectively. ... food for thought.

Comment: ^yes, that is how it would be made testable.  kudos for blesh

Comment: If you want a module that already does this for you, check out my answer below about angular-moment (including a usage example).

Answer (score 20):

You can use the `am-time-ago` directive from [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) module (which is based on [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)).

It does not require jQuery, and the time get updated as time progresses. Example:

```
<span am-time-ago="lastLoginTime"></span>
```

The content of the above span will be replaced with a relative time string, for example "2 hours ago", and will be automatically updated as time progresses.

Comment: Great find urish! Works and updates live as stated, note: Don't forget to add the dependency in your app, see the angular-moment docs.

Comment: @urish: Is there any way to use `am-time-ago` with a custom format, e.g. "2h" instead of "2 hours ago"?

Comment: See here for an answer about customizing the format of `am-time-ago`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22964767/how-to-format-angular-moments-am-time-ago-directive

Answer (score 6):

moment.js is the best choice. I have created a generic moment filter that allow you to use any moment formatting method.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .filter('moment', [
    function () {
      return function (date, method) {
        var momented = moment(date);
        return momented[method].apply(momented, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2));
      };
    }
  ]);
```

Use it like

```
<div>{{ date | moment:'fromNow' }}</div>
<div>{{ date | moment:'calendar' }}</div>
```

You can checkout it in action here http://jsfiddle.net/gregwym/7207osvw/

Answer (score 4):

If you need jQuery, writing a directive/filter is the way to go.

```
app.directive("timeAgo", function($compile) {
  return {  
    restrict: "C",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      jQuery(element).timeago();
    }
  };
});

app.filter("timeAgo", function() {
  return function(date) {
    return jQuery.timeago(date); 
  };
});
```

[Directive and/or Filter (jsbin)](http://jsbin.com/eromij/1/edit)

Comment: Using a directive is the only way to have the datetime automatically update as time progresses.

Comment: The "$compile" dependency is unnecessary for the directive.

Comment: The above directive does not handle the case when the datetime in the "title" attribute is generated "{{ ... }}" syntax. See https://gist.github.com/JensRantil/5470122 for an improvement that fixes this.