# How to format 'angular-moment's 'am-time-ago' directive?

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/soresigi/1/edit)

I use the [`am-time-ago`](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#timeago-directive) directive to show a relative timestamp:

```
<span am-time-ago="publishedAt"></span>
```

By default, it is formatted as "a day ago", "5 days ago", etc.

How could I change the formatting to be "1d", "5d", "3h", etc?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could customize humanize, somewhere in your config or app start.

```
moment.lang('en', {
    relativeTime : {
        future: "in %s",
        past:   "%s ago",
        s:  "%d seconds",
        m:  "1m",
        mm: "%dm",
        h:  "1h",
        hh: "%dh",
        d:  "1d",
        dd: "%dd",
        M:  "1m",
        MM: "%dm",
        y:  "1y",
        yy: "%dy"
    }
});

x = new moment();
z = x.clone().add('hours',1);
x.from(z, false);
>> 1h ago
x.from(z, true) //no ago
>> 1h
```

Docs on [realtiveTime](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/)

Example:  http://jsbin.com/satohazu/1/edit

Comment: Thank for that! In case of "3 months" or "2 years", is that possible to format it using days, e.g. "90d" or "730d"?

Comment: This doesn't have the correct syntax for every measure. For instance `mm: "%m"` should be `mm: "%dm"`.

Comment: Any ideas how to set two different langs (I mean formats for minutes/seconds etc) for different controllers? In other words, In one box I need to display: 20 minutes ago, but in the second box, 20 min.

Comment: @jsmiff I updated the above but its just an example of how to remap.  Feel free to update them to whatever you want.

Comment: @SebastianBochan I could recommend a hack (define an "abbreviated" locale) but i dont know of how to format `timeago` out of the box.

Comment: Do you mean part with  clone() and from() ?

Comment: Has anyone used this in an Ionic project? can't seem the get dates to format properly, as they just revert back the original "A few seconds ago" format.

Comment: @MishaMoroshko Yes 90d instead of 3m (months) can apparently be "configured" as shown here: https://github.com/urish/angular-moment/issues/44#issuecomment-40210140

Comment: I all languages are required then this might be an option: https://github.com/catamphetamine/javascript-time-ago

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer by Nix works, but is deprecated by now. Anybody who stumbles across this discussion (like I did) should use `moment.updateLocale(locale)`.

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    relativeTime : {
        future: "in %s",
        past:   "%s ago",
        s:  "%d seconds",
        m:  "1m",
        mm: "%dm",
        h:  "1h",
        hh: "%dh",
        d:  "1d",
        dd: "%dd",
        M:  "1m",
        MM: "%dm",
        y:  "1y",
        yy: "%dy"
    }
});
```

Details at https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/