# Time Ago using Moment.js and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, momentjs

I'm using Angular with the [`angular-moment`](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) package. Using the `am-time-ago` directive

```
<span am-time-ago="message.time"></span>
```

gives results like `5 hours ago`, `a day ago`, `15 days ago`.

**Questoin**: How can we get it to format into a custom format `5d`, `1d`, `15d`?

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22964767/how-to-format-angular-moments-am-time-ago-directive

Comment: http://mattbradley.github.io/livestampjs/