# can anyone know how to display 1 min ago in chat window by taking the difference between the time

Tags: angularjs

i have to display the time difference from the current time in angularjs .

created time  2015-09-01T10:59:00.568Z

current time  2015-09-01T11:00:00.568Z.

can anyone know how to display 1 min ago in a chat application window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use jQuery timeago or momentjs and AngularJS together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774486/use-jquery-timeago-or-momentjs-and-angularjs-together)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `angular-moment.js` to display `min ago` in chat window.

here is the [github Repo #timeago-directive](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#timeago-directive)

Comment: thanks gaurav bhavsar